# Android app crashing on rotation

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, crash

Whenever I rotate the device, the app crashes and I can't figure out why. Here is the LogCat info:

```
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cleanlist/com.cleanlist.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3554)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1230)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:466)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at com.cleanlist.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:307)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1861)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5058)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
07-26 10:11:48.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25775):    ... 12 more
```

Here is the section of code where it has the problem at, and it points the problem to listView.setAdapter(listadapter);

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public transient ListObject list;
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        private View thisView;
        private MainActivity mainActivity;
        private CustomListAdapter listadapter;


        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        public DummySectionFragment(MainActivity act, CustomListAdapter adp, ListObject thisList)
        {
            list = thisList;
            mainActivity = act;
            listadapter = adp;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);

                final int whichList = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

                listadapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_row, list);
                ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
                if (listView != null)
                    listView.setAdapter(listadapter);
                else
                    Log.e("wbbug","ListView is NULL");
                listView.setSelection(1);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) 
                    {
                      Log.d("wbbug","List item click: " + position + "List size: " + list.size());

                    }
                });

            thisView = rootView;
            return rootView;
        }
```

Comment: it seems thisList becomes null in your activity or something

Answer (score 0):

There is a null pointer exception in the ArrayAdapter getCount method. So most probably your list has become null. On rotation, the activity will be recreated and maybe your list is not getting initialized properly.